# Member list omit Admin Account from List

Tags: php, html, authentication, member

I am working on my website and I have a basic table to display members of people who have registered. I however don't want to display the Admin account on the table. Is there any way to exclude a username/id from the table in this case, the admin? Thanks in advanced, Josh

Here is my code for the member list table:

```
<?php 

    include("include/session.php");

/**
 * displayUsers - Displays the users database table in
 * a nicely formatted html table.
 */
function displayUsers(){

      $levels = array('1'=>'Member','2'=>'Supporter','3'=>'Donor','4'=>'VIP','5'=>'Veteran','7'=>'Co-Founder','8'=>'Founder','9'=>'Admin');
    //do_query
    //loop results
    $ulevel = mysql_result($result,$i,"userlevel"); $ulevel = $levels[$ulevel];
    //continue loop

   global $database;
   $q = "SELECT username,userlevel,email,timestamp "
       ."FROM ".TBL_USERS." ORDER BY userlevel DESC,username";
   $result = $database->query($q);
   /* Error occurred, return given name by default */
   $num_rows = mysql_numrows($result);
   if(!$result || ($num_rows < 0)){
      echo "Error displaying info";
      return;
   }
   if($num_rows == 0){
      echo "Database table empty";
      return;
   }
   /* Display table contents */
   echo "<table align=\"left\" border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\">\n";
   echo "<tr><td><b>Username</b></td><td><b>Level</b></td><td><b>Last Active</b></td></tr>\n";
   for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
      $uname  = mysql_result($result,$i,"username");
      $ulevel = $levels[mysql_result($result,$i,"userlevel")];
      $time   = mysql_result($result,$i,"timestamp");

      echo "<tr><td>$uname</td><td>$ulevel</td><td>$time</td></tr>\n";
   }
   echo "</table><br>\n";


}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update your query:

```
$q = "SELECT username,userlevel,email,timestamp "
       ."FROM ".TBL_USERS." where userlevel<>'Admin' ORDER BY userlevel DESC,username";
```

If you use PDO library:

```
...
$adminLevel = 'Admin';
$q = "SELECT username,userlevel,email,timestamp "
     ."FROM ".TBL_USERS." where userlevel <> ? ORDER BY userlevel DESC,username";
$statement = $database->prepare($q);  
$result = $statement->execute(array($adminLevel));

... // Go on with the rest of your code
```

Comment: I put it in and it said:Fatal error: Call to undefined method MySQLDB::prepare() on this line  $statement = $database->prepare($q);
thanks for you help btw

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this accordingly..

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE level <> 'admin'
```